# How to add item right after selected item in listview in VB .NET

Tags: vb.net

I wrote piece of cod for add item right after selected item in listview:

```vb
Private Sub InsertBeforeToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles InsertBeforeToolStripMenuItem.Click

        
        ListView1.Items.Add(Me.ListView1.Items(ListView1.SelectedIndices(0) + 1).Clone)

        For i = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1

            ListView1.Items(i).Text = i + 1.ToString

        Next
end sub
```

but its not work this cod add item to end of listview instead of after selected item
The question is how can i achive that purpose? thank you all.

Comment: Definitely something fishy going on there..

Comment: @CaiusJard you are funny dude:))))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
If(ListView1.SelectedIndices.Count > 0) Then
  ListView1.Items.Insert(ListView1.SelectedIndices(0) + 1, "new item")
Else
  ListView1.Items.Add("new item")
End If
```

[image]

Comment: No, unfortunately It does not work, it gives an error in ListView1.SelectedIndex

Comment: "Does not work" is a particularly useless description of the state of affairs; put your tech support hat on and deliver a problem report that you yourself would *want* to receive if you were working helpdesk. "My computer doesn't work" is not an example ;)

Comment: Works for me.. If the "insert after first selected item" didn't work, there's no way I could have got item 7 into that position..?

Comment: @CaiusJard dear caiusjard I realized why it doesn't work for me because my listview has four columns.
What should I do with these conditions?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for something like `ListView1.Items.Insert(ListView1.SelectedIndices[0] + 1, new ListViewItem("thing"+ListView1.Items.Count)).SubItems.AddRange({ "1", "2", "3" })` - the 1,2,3 being your other 3 columns.

Comment: @CaiusJard WWWOWWWW This is exactly what I was looking for and it worked beautifully.
Thank you millions of times for your help and guidance and you are the best.